# Is this a system of linear equations in five variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

There is a question asking which of the following are systems of linear equations in variables $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$, and $x_5$.

And there is a choice, a system containing
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{}x_1+x_3+x_5 =8\\  x_2+x_4+x_6 =9\\  x_3+x_5+x_7=4\end{array}\right.$$

Is this choice satisfying the system of linear equations in variables $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$, and $x_5$? I found $x_6$ and $x_7$, which are not listed in the question. However, my math teacher once said that $x_1$ or $x_2$ are just symbols representing the variable, which could also be $y$. Therefore, I am not sure whether $x_6, x_7$ are the same. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's an underdetermined system, without more information, you would find it near impossible to solve.

Comment: Yes. But my professor said it can be linear equation as though it may not be solved.

Comment: @Kevin: Not sure why you think it would be so difficult. Where did you get stuck? I solved it immediately using Gaußian elimination and introduction of appropriate parameters..

Comment: @MårtenW I didn't get stuck, to me it is a system of seven variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### YES!

If you consider $x_6$ and $x_7$ as *parameters* and not as unknowns, then the system in your question is a perfectly fine system of linear equations in $x_1,\ldots,x_5$.

---

Gaußian elimination shows that
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x_1+x_3+x_5 &= 8 \\
x_2+x_4+x_6 &= 9 \\
x_3+x_5+x_7 &= 4
\end{aligned}
\right.
\Leftrightarrow
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x_1 &= 4 + x_7 \\
x_2 &= t_2 \\
x_3 &= t_3 \\
x_4 &= 9 - x_ 6 - t_2 \\
x_5 &= 4 - x_7 - t_3
\end{aligned}
\right.,
$$
which gives a parametrisation of the solution space in terms of the parameters $t_2,t_3,x_6,x_7\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ok, then please add your working to this answer. I'd be keen to see it.

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks for the downvote. I have added an explicit parametrisation of the solution space.

Comment: I did not downvote, these rep points are irrelevant to me. I actually was keen to see your working, fwiw, I will +1.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: No matter how you choose to label the variables, this system of equations has 7 distinct variables, not 5.

Comment: Thank you very much! Got that^_^

Comment: @gandalf61: How do you know that $x_6$ and $x_7$ are not meant to be parameters?

Comment: I am applying common sense. Using $x_1$ to $x_5$ to denote variables and $x_6$ and $x_7$ to denote parameters would be bizzare, arbitrary and confusing. If you consider $x_6$ and $x_7$ to be paraneters then how do you know that $x_5$ is not also a parameter - in which case there are actually only 4 variables here ?

Comment: @gandalf61: My point is precisely that the question is ill-posed and up to interpretation.